# DTLS Record with weird cipher text

Tags: encryption, tls, wireshark

I am using [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) to deploy each a DTLS Server and a DTLS Client application. After the DTLS Handshake, the Client sends "Hi, Server" and then the Server answers "Hi Client". The connection is working fine and running.
(The negotiated Cipher Suite is `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`)

However, when I analyze the encrypted Application Data packets using Wireshark, I see a weird cipher text. The encrypted application data always seems to start with **`00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01`**. Shouldn't it be pseudorandom? Might this be padding (and if, why this sequence)?

First Message ("Hi Server"):

`0000   17 fe fd 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 21 00 01 00  ............!...`
`0010   00 00 00 00 01 f3 5f 8c 78 0f cf 25 08 54 ed 1c  ......_.x..%.T..`
`` 0020   60 ec b2 fe 05 bc ce e9 fe b5 f6 28 e6 e4        `..........(.. ``

```
       17                    Content Type:    Application Data
       fe fd                 Version:         DTLS 1.2
       00 01                 Epoch:           1
       00 00 00 00 00 01     Sequence Number: 1
       00 21                 Length:          33
       00 ... e4             Encrypted Application Data
```

Second Message ("Hi Client"):

`0000   17 fe fd 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 21 00 01 00  ............!...`
`0010   00 00 00 00 01 74 9d 2b 3f f4 6d 75 f1 47 a6 12  .....t.+?.mu.G..`
`` 0020   7c c1 7d 5e 49 13 69 c9 57 72 60 df 90 56        |.}^I.i.Wr`..V ``

```
       17                    Content Type:    Application Data
       fe fd                 Version:         DTLS 1.2
       00 01                 Epoch:           1
       00 00 00 00 00 01     Sequence Number: 1
       00 21                 Length:          33
       00 ... 56             Encrypted Application Data
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are asking the correct people about this. You are asking why a certain library does something. I think this is a question for the devs

Comment: @schroeder I actually don't know if this is due to the (D)TLS standard or the implementation.

Comment: @MemAllox this is in the opaque fragment part of a DTLS frame according to the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4347#section-4

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, I already peaked inside the DTLS Standard (RFC6347 is the current one). Unfortunately I did neither find something useful there nor where the Cipher Suite is defined (RFC5289). There are simply too many RFCs :D

Comment: Because the way the opaque fragment is done is up to each library, That's more or less dependent on the cypher used than on DTLS I think.

Comment: You are probably right. This is probably a mechanism of the Cipher Suite I use. I don't think that this is implementation specific though (because of interoperablility). Thanks!

Comment: I did say, dependent on the cypher used, not on the library, I didn't dig into each cypher payload format to confirm, but I "suspect" this data start is the encryption header for ECDHE/ECDSA to tell the payload is done with this method.

Comment: GCM suites in [D]TLS use AEAD format (rfc5246 6.2.3.3) which begins with **explicit nonce (part)** of length defined by the suite; GCM suites use 8 bytes (rfc5288 3) which 'MAY be [a copy of] the 64-bit sequence number' and this implementation does make it so. (This is not affected by the keyexchange used.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You're absolutely right! If you want, you can write an answer which I can accept. Otherwise, I'll write one myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dave_thompson_085 suggested, the sequence at the beginning of the encrypted application data is the **explicit nonce** used by the GCM (Galois Counter Mode). Apparently, this is some kind of initialisation vector shared with the peer. Note that there might be an implicit part of the nonce which is not sent over wire.

[The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol (RFC5246), 6.2.3.3. AEAD Ciphers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.3):

> For AEAD [...] ciphers (such as [CCM] or [GCM]), the AEAD function
> converts TLSCompressed.fragment structures to and from AEAD
> TLSCiphertext.fragment structures.
>
> ```
>   struct {
>      opaque nonce_explicit[SecurityParameters.record_iv_length];
>      aead-ciphered struct {
>          opaque content[TLSCompressed.length];
>      };
>   } GenericAEADCipher;
> ```

You can clearly see here, that the Ciphertext is preceded by `nonce_explicit`.

---

After some testing, i noticed that these bytes seems to involve a counter that increments with each sent message. Now I asked myself what sort of information is sent there?

[RFC5246, 6.2.3.3.  AEAD Ciphers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.3):

> Each AEAD
> cipher suite MUST specify how the nonce supplied to the    AEAD
> operation is constructed, and what is the length of the    `GenericAEADCipher.nonce_explicit` part

This means that I have to find the RFC where the AES with GCM is specified for TLS. Again, dave_thompson_085 also led me to this answer.

[AES Galois Counter Mode (GCM) Cipher Suites for TLS (RFC5288), 3. AES-GCM Cipher Suites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288#section-3):

> Each value of the nonce_explicit MUST be distinct for each distinct
> invocation of the GCM encrypt function for any fixed key.  Failure to
> meet this uniqueness requirement can significantly degrade security.
> The nonce_explicit MAY be the 64-bit sequence number.

So these bytes are the explicit part of the nonce as specified in TLS. The implemtation (mbedTLS) used the sequence number for it. Thanks again to dave_thompson_085!